# What is the best way to show an item has been added to a list in iOS?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-expectation, ios, apple

I have a list item in an iOS app that is ordered alphabetically.

[image]

When adding a new item to this list, there is no way to easily tell that this item has been appended - especially if your list is really long, you would have to scroll down to check if it actually has been added.

If the list was ordered chronologically, that would probably solve the problem since you'd see your newly added item topmost, but we'd like to keep it alphabetical.

Any suggestions on how to go about it? Perhaps a solution that is already a standard in iOS (if any)?

Answer (score 4):

You can consider few ways to go about it.

1. Simply just display a alert box saying "Item added to to list successfully".
2. when the item is added, automatically scroll it down to the position where it is located in the list, highlight it (may be with a color fade), for few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought of 2 as well, but do you know if highlighting is standard in iOS? I've come across apps that scroll to position once an item has been appended to the list, but they never get highlighted. I'm sure this is something we can implement, but just curious if it's a standard or not.

Comment: I don't think it is the standard. And I don't think there is any standard solution for your specific situation. But, Highlighting would give the necessary **feedback** to the user that which item has been appended to the list.